# Spark SQL different partitions with the same Row

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to insert Spark SQL Row values into the database with a code like the following:

```
final Broadcast<String> jdbcUrl = sc.broadcast(config.jdbcUrl());
df.foreachPartition((final Iterator<Row> it) -> {
    final Sql2o sql2o = new Sql2o(jdbcUrl.value(), null, null, new NoQuirks());
    try (final Connection conn = sql2o.beginTransaction()) {
        final String sql = "INSERT INTO Table (Id, Value) VALUES (:id, :value)";
        final Query query = conn.createQuery(sql, false);
        int batchSize = 0;
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            final Row row = it.next();
            query.addParameter("id", row.getLong(0))
                .addParameter("value", row.get(1));
                .addToBatch();
            if (++batchSize == 1000) {
                query.executeBatch();
                conn.commit();
                batchSize = 0;
            }
        }
        query.executeBatch();
        conn.commit();
    }
});
```

And I'm getting a Primary Key Violation error:

> java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint
>   'PK_Table'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'Table'. The
>   duplicate key value is 42.

I added some debug logging code, and I verified that two different executors were trying to insert the same Row (with the same id and value).

The table is empty before Spark SQL starts inserting the Row values. Also, I've tried calling `distinct()` and `persist()` before calling `foreachPartition()` on the DataFrame, and I still get the issue.

Shouldn't different partitions of the same DataFrame have separate data? Don't partitioners always guarantee that?

**EDIT:**

I ran `df.groupBy(df.col("id")).count().filter(col("count").gt(1)).show();` on the DataFrame and there is no id that groups to more than one Row:

```
+--+-----+
|id|count|
+--+-----+
+--+-----+
```

From what I can figure out, looks like the same partition is being iterated simultaneously in different executors. How come?

Comment: Why do you have Microsoft SQL-Server tagged if this isn't a SQL Server question?

Comment: @pmbAustin, fair enough. I removed the tag.

Comment: As your error code says: 42. This is the answer ;) 

Ok, now real suggestion: `distinct()` makes distinct rows. That means, that you can have 2x the same ID, but second value will be different. Try to do `groupBy('id).count`

Comment: @T.Gawęda, and compare it with just the `df.count`?

Comment: No, filter it to values higher than 1

Comment: @T.Gawęda, thanks for the suggestion. Just updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, column indexes are wrong; "id" not in 0 column. Better:

```
userow.getAs[Long]("id")
```

instead of row.getLong(0)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Tried that, and I'm getting the issue.  :- (